# RuntimeException on SlidePuzzle Source Code from Sporksoft

Tags: java, android, puzzle

I'm trying to run the slidepuzzle source code from Sporksoft at:
http://code.google.com/p/sporksoft/source/browse/#svn/trunk/slidepuzzle

I'm not getting any errors prior to launching the code.  The only warning is "Attribute minSdkVersion (3) is lower than the project target API level (8)" which I'm assuming would not affect the app from running (correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm still learning java/android and I'm having trouble trying to figure out what's causing the runtime error:

```
 Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1618    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1716 
ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 124   
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 968   
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 130 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3806    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

screenshot of eclipse debug:

[image: debug]

I've tried running the app on the emulator and also on 2 android phones.  It crashes on all.

Do you have any idea what might be causing the app to crash?

Thanks!  Any help is appreciated.
Shannon

Comment: Under Variables when the app crashes I'm getting: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sporksoft.slidepuzzle.SlidePuzzleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sporksoft.slidepuzzle-2.apk].  I've went into the properties and attempted to see if I could resolve, but nothing worked.  Would this be causing the problem?  If so, what changes do I need to make?  Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it figured out.  For those who might want to use the same script and having the same issues as I did.

It was only fluke that I figured it out, but it seems to be working. The only issue I have is that I have a lot of warnings now.  I'll have to figure that out another day.  At least the app is running now which is more than it's been doing! :-)

In order to fix I had to fix the java build path in the package properties.

Here's how I setup my build path that resolved the problem:

[image: Source]
[image: Libraries]

The Google 2.1 library is located under the "Add Library" button, then Android Classpath Container.  I had trouble locating this. :-)